# Minimize doesn't give result / takes very long

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am stuck with a minimization problem:

```
FullSimplify[
 Assuming[a1 >= 0 && a2 >= 0 && w1 >= 0 & w2 >= 0 && b1 > 0 && 
   b2 > 0 && 0 <= α1 < 1 && 0 <= α2 < 1 && P1 > 0 && 
   P2 > 0 ,  
  Minimize[w1 + w2 + (
    b1 (2 b1 + 4 P1 + 2 a2 α1 - 6 P α1 - 
       a2 α1^2 + 2 P1 α1^2))/(-2 + α1)^2 + (
    b2 (2 b2 + 4 P2 + 2 a1 α2 - 6 P α2 - 
       a1 α2^2 + 2 P2 α2^2))/(-2 + α2)^2, {w1 + 
      b1*a1 - (a1 - ((1 - α1) * 
            P1 + α1 *((a1 + a2)/2)))^2 >= 0,  
    w2 + b2*a2 - (a2 - ((1 - α2) * 
            P2 + α2 *((a2 + a1)/2)))^2 >= 0},  {w1, w2, a1, 
    a2, b1, b2}, Reals]]]
```

Is there any possibility to yield a solution in this case? Even after running approximately an hour, there is no output yet.

Comment: Try `NMinimize`, maybe. This problem seems complicated enough that an analytic solution is either impossible or unlikely to be useful. In addition, it is probably necessary to put your constraints as equations inside `NMinimize`, rather than in an enclosing `Assuming` construct.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this numerically, since it very unlikely you will get an analytic expression. Of course, you will need to choose values for the undefined parameters. Since

```
0 <= α1 < 1
0 <= α2 < 1
P1 > 0
P2 > 0
```

I have chosen some values:

```
With[{P1 = 1, P2 = 2, α1 = 0.5, α2 = 0.5, P = 1},
  NMinimize[{
     w1 + w2 + (b1 (2 b1 + 4 P1 + 2 a2 α1 - 6 P α1 - a2 α1^2 + 2 P1 α1^2))/(-2 + α1)^2 + (b2 (2 b2 + 4 P2 + 2 a1 α2 - 6 P α2 - a1 α2^2 + 2 P2 α2^2))/(-2 + α2)^2,
     w1 + b1*a1 - (a1 - ((1 - α1)*P1 + α1*((a1 + a2)/2)))^2 >= 0,
     w2 + b2*a2 - (a2 - ((1 - α2)*P2 + α2*((a2 + a1)/2)))^2 >= 0,
     a1 >= 0, a2 >= 0, w1 >= 0, w2 >= 0, b1 > 0, b2 > 0
    },
   {w1, w2, a1, a2, b1, b2},
   Reals]
 ]
```

The output is quick:

```
{2.25268*10^-8, {w1 -> 0., w2 -> 2.25268*10^-8, a1 -> 1.24999, a2 -> 1.74998, b1 -> 0., b2 -> 0.}}
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't find a better way than doing it numerically. However, how can it be that the output for variables `b1 -> 0., b2 -> 0` is zero, which obviously violates the constraints in the program above which state  `b1 > 0, b2 > 0` ?

Comment: It just means that the minimum is where `b1, b2` is as close to 0 as you can numerically resolve. Just think of the smallest machine-precision real number larger than 0 or something.